# TFS 2010 Build Definition: MSBuild Arguments seems to be ignored

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-definition

I am trying to create a package after a build in TFS 2010.

When I launch the following command on my computer:

```
 MSBuild.exe Fenicorp.Front.Web.FunnyApplication.sln 
 /p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package
```

the solution is compiled and there is a package inside the obj folder.

However, when I specify

```
 /p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package
```

as MSBuild Arguments in a Build Definition and queue a new build, there is no package in my drop folder. Moreover the build status is Successfull, as if everything is fine.

Comment: Check on the build agent -- did the package get created there?  Maybe it just isn't being copied to the drop location?

Comment: Where should I look on the build agent?

Comment: In the BuildTemp folder on the server where the build agent is running.

Comment: I didn't find a BuildTemp folder on the server but I found this folder:  C:\Users\builduser\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp which is empty.

I found out where the build agent put the files, but it turns out the build agent folder contains exactly the same thing that the drop folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I managed to make it work.
I needed to install Visual Studio 2010 on the build server in order to have MSBuild to work with these arguments.

Comment: I had this same issue which was doing my nut. It's so annoying that you need to install VS to make it work!!

Comment: Very likely - all you need to do is install the associated target file not all of Visual Studio..

Comment: You do not need VS on the build machine, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352546/tfs-build-definition-not-deploying-mvc-application-to-iis/13983872