# Team Foundation Server 2012 Automated Build Target Location

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a solution in VS2012 and when I do a publish in VS it drops the compiled code to the target location with the following structure

```
\bin
\Content
\Properties
\Scripts
\Services
... etc.
```

When the TFS 2012 automated build runs it drops the code into my target location with the following structure

```
MyProject_Build\MyProject_Build_20130823.5\_PublishedWebsites\MyProject\bin
MyProject_Build\MyProject_Build_20130823.5\_PublishedWebsites\MyProject\Content
... etc.
```

I would like to drop the code into the location like the first example, or at least

```
\MyProject\bin
... etc.
```

The idea is to publish the compiled code to the same exact location every time so that IIS knows where the code is right?

How can I change this?

Comment: Is there nothing other than _PublishedWebsites?

Comment: In the `MyProject_Build_20130823.5` directory? Yes there is also a logs folder and some `.dll`, `.xml` and `.pdb` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something TFS doesn't support out of the box but with Process Template customization you can definitely do it.

However, I would suggest updating the website directly using msdeploy. If you just have to update one website then it is very easy using msdeploy commands in TFS(https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706005/581922).

Edit:
Based upon your comment you will have to customize the build process. [Ewald Hofman](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-14-Execute-a-PowerShell-script.aspx) has a great series of articles on how to customize TFS Build process templates to suit your needs.

If you want to customize the TFS Process Template then

1. You can either do everything in powershell but invoking a powershell script as Ewald demonstrates.  I have written a blog post on how to deploy websites to [IIS using MSdeploy, Powershell and TFSBuild](http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2012/06/deploying-website-and-windows-service.html)
2. Use InvokeProcess Activitiy in TFSProcess template and use Xcopy to copy files to destination folder on the server you want.

You might also want to check this [post](http://donovanbrown.com/post/how-to-xcopy-deploy-using-tfs-2010.aspx).

Comment: It's not just one website, this is just one example. I'm fine with it putting the build in that structure, I don't mind having the historical builds. However, I also need it to deploy the code to the web service in the folder that IIS is looking for it. What change to the Build process template do I need to make to do that?

Comment: Do I really have to use an external script to do this? It seems to me that I should be able to configure the Process Template to change the folder structure/location of the output. I would really prefer not to separately manage PowerShell scripts to do a deploy. To me that's a bad solution for Continuous Integration. I should simply be able to add a "deploy" activity to the Process Template or modify the configuration of the build.

Comment: That's what my step 2 is you can customize process template to invoke process and use xcopy and do whatever you want.

Comment: oh ok, I don't see xcopy anywhere?

Comment: Do I use the "CopyDirectory" activity?

Comment: You can do that or use InvokeProcess Activity and then in the parameters option you can specify Xcopy.

Comment: Check this too. -http://donovanbrown.com/post/how-to-xcopy-deploy-using-tfs-2010.aspx

Comment: I actually just found that article a few minutes ago. However, when I add parameters it's not the same. Maybe something changed between 2010 and 2012. I can't set all those options up that he has on his parameters and the parameters I add don't show up on the build definition for me to put values into.

Comment: Thanks! The solution you mentioned here: `http://donovanbrown.com/post/how-to-xcopy-deploy-using-tfs-2010.aspx` works, although I had to use "DropLocation" rather than "BinariesDirectory" in the Source. +1

Answer (score 0):

Create publish profiles for your website and choose publish method as file copy and choose the shares folder location where you want to copy the files. In the tfs build template, in ms build parameters options choose the publish profile you created.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Production;
```

Comment: How do I create a publish profile? and where do I add these `/p:...` settings?

Comment: More about publish profiles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx you have to give that settings in msbuild parameters in your build template. It's in the process section.